# java encoding file in windows-1252 appears Big5 in notepad++

Tags: java, character-encoding, windows-1252

I'm facing a problem when I write files with the encoding "windows-1252" : I don't know exactly when but sometimes, the files are encoded in Big5 (Chenese). I control the encoding in notepad++

For exampe, the string "¤idParam¤vidProduit1¤¤idParam2¤v2¤v" is well encoded (in a windows-1252 file) but the string "¤¤idParam¤vidProduit1¤¤idParam2¤v2¤v" does not !

I am testing it with eclipse Mars and the jdk1.8.0_92.

My code to test it :

```
  @Test
public void testFichier() throws Exception {
    File file1 = new File("target/file_ko.txt");
    Writer writer1 = Files.newBufferedWriter(file1.toPath(), Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
    writer1.write("¤¤idParam¤vidProduit1¤¤idParam2¤v2¤v");// ko
    writer1.close();

    File file2 = new File("target/file_ok.txt");
    Writer writer2 = Files.newBufferedWriter(file2.toPath(), Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
    writer2.write("¤idParam¤vidProduit1¤¤idParam2¤v2¤v");// ok
    writer2.close();

}
```

The file "file_ok.txt" is "ANSI" in notepad++ whereas the file "file_ko.txt" is "Big5 Traditional" in notepad++

I have tested lots of cases but I didn't identify what is the problem, very strange...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Big5 Traditional" also uses ASCII, and your files are both ASCII. NotePad++ is just confused. If you select to view file in ANSI, you'll see nothing changed.

Comment: Curious: If you're going to use [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), which works with [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), why use [`new File("...")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-) and not [`Paths.get("...")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)?

Comment: It's just to test it. How to know the real encoding so ? When I put the file_ko in chrome, I see Big5 in "more tools > coding"

Comment: It appears that it is not a problem but an interpretation of notepad++, the file is well encoded.